# Are the Unforgivable Curses 'Unforgivable' outside of Britain's magic community?

Tags: harry-potter, unforgivable-curse

B. Crouch Jr, while posing as Mad-Eye Moody, tells his DADA students that using any of the 'Unforgivable Curses' on a human being in Britain is punishable by life in Azkaban- do the wizard/witch populations in other countries have a similar stance?

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that the answer is "we don't know", but I look forward to being surprised.

Answer (score 10):

#### They’re only specifically stated to be outlawed in Britain, but most likely are illegal in other countries as well.

It’s not actually known if the Unforgivable Curses are legal in countries other than Britain. The law against specifically the three curses of Avada Kedavra, Crucio, and Imperio was created by the British Ministry of Magic, so that law wouldn’t affect other countries. While it is currently unknown if other countries have similar laws against those three specific curses (Crucio, Imperio, and Avada Kedavra), it seems likely that they would.

> “In Beedle’s time, the Cruciatus Curse had not yet been made illegal by the Ministry of Magic,19 and could have produced precisely the sensation with which Babbitty threatens the King.” 
> <sub><sup>*- The Tales of Beedle the Bard*</sup></sub>

The Cruciatus, Imperius and Avada Kedavra curses were classified as Unforgivable by the British Ministry of Magic in 1717. Other countries may have different ideas of what constitutes a curse that the use of which is punishable by law, though it seems likely that in most other countries, these three curses would be considered harmful enough to be made illegal.

> “19 The Cruciatus, Imperius, and Avada Kedavra curses were first classified as Unforgivable in 1717, with the strictest penalties attached to their use.” 
> <sub><sup>*- The Tales of Beedle the Bard*</sup></sub>

One bends a person to the caster’s will, one kills immediately, and one causes unbearable pain - it seems likely that other countries would have laws against their use.

Comment: If it was made illegal in 1717, it's entirely possible that it's also illegal in America along with the other former colonies of the British Empire.

Comment: Heck, at least two of the curses are illegal in most *muggle* jurisdictions!